# SUM within a loop - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have those tables:

**Table `alltransations`**

[image]

**Table `alladdon_list`**

[image]

I just want to simple `sum` up all addons with specific `transac_id` and `group` it by `guest_id` so I can get the result as this:

[image]

But with my `query`:

```
<table border=1 cellpadding=5 >
    <tr>
        <th>Names</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>

<?php

include("conn_archive.php");

$cfaddontotal = 0;

$getall = mysql_query("SELECT *, sum(quantity) as quantity,price
                        FROM alltransactions at, alladdon_list aal
                        WHERE at.transac_id=aal.aatransac_id
                        GROUP BY guest_id
                        ", $db2);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getall)){
        // GUEST INFO
        $guest_fname = $rows['guest_fname'];
        $guest_lname = $rows['guest_lname'];

        // ADDON INFO
        $addondesc = $rows['description'];
        $addondate = $rows['datef'];
        $addonqty = $rows['quantity'];
        $addonprice = $rows['price'];
        $addontcost = $addonprice * $addonqty; // cost of specific product
        $cfaddontotal += $addonprice * $addonqty; // total cost of all products

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$guest_fname $guest_lname</td>";
        echo "<td>&#8369; ".number_format($addontcost)."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}

?>
<tr>
    <th colspan=2 >Total Addon Cost: &#8369; <?php echo number_format($cfaddontotal); ?></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

I got this(which is wrong):

[image]

Can't figure out what `query` to use to get the accurate computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is confusing. Your are summing quantity of all products(with different prices) and multiplying by one "random" price (it would be good if select with `group by` did not contain fields without aggregate functions: [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)).

It's better to change your query to something

```
SELECT *, sum(quantity*price) as total
                    FROM alltransactions at, alladdon_list aal
                    WHERE at.transac_id=aal.aatransac_id
                    GROUP BY guest_id
```

Comment: Oh. Simple as that? Can't figure that out. Thanks. It works :)